# VBA extract data from Power Queries of PDF file

Tags: vba

I want to run a macros to get data from a PDF file, and after extract data from PDF file, I also need a code to get data from queries like this, See screenshot below.
[queuries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66CF1.png)

***Everytime, the data from PDF has different tables and pages, so how can I run the macros for different pdf file with different number of tables and pages

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table001 (Page 1)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table001 = Source{[Id=""Table001""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table001,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table002 (Page 1)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table002 = Source{[Id=""Table002""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table002,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table003 (Page 1)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table003 = Source{[Id=""Table003""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table003,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type duration}, {""Column6""," & _
        " type text}, {""Column7"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table004 (Page 1)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table004 = Source{[Id=""Table004""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table004,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", typ" & _
        "e text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table005 (Page 2)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table005 = Source{[Id=""Table005""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table005,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", typ" & _
        "e text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table006 (Page 3)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table006 = Source{[Id=""Table006""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table006,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", typ" & _
        "e text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table007 (Page 4)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table007 = Source{[Id=""Table007""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table007,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table008 (Page 4)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table008 = Source{[Id=""Table008""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table008,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table009 (Page 4)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table009 = Source{[Id=""Table009""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table009,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type duration}, {""Column6""," & _
        " type text}, {""Column7"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table010 (Page 4)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table010 = Source{[Id=""Table010""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table010,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", typ" & _
        "e text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table011 (Page 5)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table011 = Source{[Id=""Table011""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table011,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table012 (Page 5)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table012 = Source{[Id=""Table012""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table012,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table013 (Page 5)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table013 = Source{[Id=""Table013""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table013,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type duration}, {""Column6""," & _
        " type text}, {""Column7"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table014 (Page 5)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table014 = Source{[Id=""Table014""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table014,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", typ" & _
        "e text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table015 (Page 6)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table015 = Source{[Id=""Table015""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table015,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", typ" & _
        "e text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table016 (Page 7)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table016 = Source{[Id=""Table016""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table016,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", typ" & _
        "e text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table017 (Page 8)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""Z:\Planning\Invoices 21442382.pdf""), [Implementation=""1.2""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Table017 = Source{[Id=""Table017""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table017,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", typ" & _
        "e text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table001 (Page 1)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table001 (Page 1)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table001 (Page 1);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table001 (Page 1)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table002 (Page 1)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table002 (Page 1)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table002 (Page 1);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table002 (Page 1)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table003 (Page 1)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table003 (Page 1)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table003 (Page 1);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table003 (Page 1)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table004 (Page 1)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table004 (Page 1)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table004 (Page 1);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table004 (Page 1)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table005 (Page 2)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table005 (Page 2)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table005 (Page 2);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table005 (Page 2)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table006 (Page 3)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table006 (Page 3)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table006 (Page 3);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table006 (Page 3)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table007 (Page 4)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table007 (Page 4)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table007 (Page 4);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table007 (Page 4)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table008 (Page 4)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table008 (Page 4)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table008 (Page 4);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table008 (Page 4)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table009 (Page 4)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table009 (Page 4)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table009 (Page 4);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table009 (Page 4)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table010 (Page 4)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table010 (Page 4)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table010 (Page 4);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table010 (Page 4)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table011 (Page 5)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table011 (Page 5)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table011 (Page 5);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table011 (Page 5)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table012 (Page 5)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table012 (Page 5)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table012 (Page 5);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table012 (Page 5)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table013 (Page 5)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table013 (Page 5)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table013 (Page 5);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table013 (Page 5)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table014 (Page 5)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table014 (Page 5)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table014 (Page 5);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table014 (Page 5)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table015 (Page 6)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table015 (Page 6)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table015 (Page 6);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table015 (Page 6)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table016 (Page 7)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table016 (Page 7)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table016 (Page 7);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table016 (Page 7)""", 6, True, False
    Workbooks("UK Invoice.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Table017 (Page 8)", _
        "Connection to the 'Table017 (Page 8)' query in the workbook.", _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table017 (Page 8);Extended Properties=" _
        , """Table017 (Page 8)""", 6, True, False
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Append1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Table.Combine({#""Table001 (Page 1)"", #""Table002 (Page 1)"", #""Table003 (Page 1)"", #""Table004 (Page 1)"", #""Table005 (Page 2)"", #""Table006 (Page 3)"", #""Table007 (Page 4)"", #""Table008 (Page 4)"", #""Table009 (Page 4)"", #""Table010 (Page 4)"", #""Table011 (Page 5)"", #""Table012 (Page 5)"", #""Table013 (Page 5)"", #""Table014 (Page 5)""," & _
        " #""Table015 (Page 6)"", #""Table016 (Page 7)"", #""Table017 (Page 8)""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source" & _
        ""
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Append1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$2")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Append1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Append1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What exact is your question?

Comment: I tried to recorded macros to get data from PDF file, I added the code in the question, but I don't know how to make the code clear, can  you show me?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [repro] - this should help you to improve your question.